# Why is my TreeMap not sorting?

Tags: java, treemap

I used a `TreeMap` where the key is a `String` and the value is of type `Integer`. When I output the `Map` object, it's not printing in sorted order.

Here's the code I used:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
m.put("Hello", 1);
m.put("world", 2);
m.put("Zertt", 5);
m.put("Hello", 1);
m.put("world", 2);
System.out.println("map : " + m);
```

I expect the output to be sorted like this :

> map : {Hello=1, world=2, Zertt=5}

But instead I get this :

> map : {Hello=1, Zertt=5, world=2}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The natural ordering of `String`s is case sensitive, so `Z` comes before `w` (all upper case letters come before all lower case letters).

Use

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

for case insensitive order.

Answer (score 2):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) says :

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its **keys**, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

*EDIT : Eran's answer is right, String ordering is case sensitive by default.*

Answer (score 1):

As answered before string natural order is case sensitive. But, if you want insentive ordering, you can provide comparator as TreeMap constructor parameter:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

p.s. Notice, when using case insentive order keys will compare insentive too:

```
m.put("Hello", 1);
m.put("helLo", 6);
```

Result is 6 and key is `Hello`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this information will be helpful.

> In the class TreeMap contains constructors:
>
> 1. TreeMap ()
> 2. TreeMap (Comparator comp)
> 3. TreeMap (Map m)
> 4. TreeMap (SortedMap sm)
>
> The first constructor creates a collection in which all the elements
>   are sorted in natural order of their keys.
>
> The second constructor creates an empty collection, the elements of
>   which will be sorted according to the law, which is defined in the
>   transmission comparator.
>
> The third constructor creates a TreeMap based on an existing Map.
>
> The fourth constructor creates a TreeMap based on existing SortedMap,
>   elements of which will be sorted according to the law transmitted
>   SortedMap.
>
> Note that keys used for the sorting, rather than the value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting in treemap is based on the natural order of keys and not values.